# Реализация Drag&Drop в C#

Tags: c#, drag-n-drop

Вот скажите как работает Drag and Drop? Как его добавить чтобы кнопки можно было перетаскивать по форме? А то очень интересная функция.

И как правильно пользоваться командной

```
Sleep
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Выполнение операции перетаскивания в Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/za0zx9y0.aspx)

Чтобы управлять активностью или временем жизни потока, надо решить массу задач. С этим позволяют справиться методы `Thread`. Например, довольно часто поток нужно приостановить. Это можно сделать, вызвав метод `Thread.Sleep`, который принимает единственный аргумент, представляющий собой время (в миллисекундах), на которое требуется приостановить поток. Заметьте: метод `Thread.Sleep` является статическим и не может быть вызван с экземпляром объекта `Thread`. На то есть веская причина. Не допускается вызывать `Thread.Sleep` для любого другого потока, кроме исполняемого в текущий момент. Статический метод `Thread.Sleep` вызывает статический же метод `CurrentThread`, который затем приостанавливает этот поток на указанное время.